# Getting value from the listview with custom adpter of selected checkbox to the activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I am stuck when trying to get the value of selected checkbox listview values in my activity. I don't know how to do it, can any one suggest me a resolution to this issue?. Here is my code :

```
public class CandidateAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {  
    Context ctxt;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<CandidateModel> candidateList = new ArrayList<CandidateModel>();
    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    public CandidateAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CandidateModel> candidateList) {      
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.candidateList = candidateList;
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(candidateList.size());
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return candidateList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CandidateModel getItem(int position) {
        return candidateList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null){   
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_candidate,null);            
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.candidateName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.candidatenametxt);              
            holder.contactNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactnumbertxt);
            holder.email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);
            holder.contactCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.contactchk);
            view.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{           
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        final CandidateModel cm = candidateList.get(position);              
        String contactNumber = cm.getContactNumber();
        String candidateName = cm.getCandidateName();
        String email = cm.getEmail();
        if(!candidateName.equals("null") && candidateName!=null)
        {
            holder.candidateName.setText(cm.getCandidateName());            
        }
        else{
            holder.candidateName.setText("confidential");
        }           
        if(!contactNumber.equals("null") && contactNumber!="" && contactNumber!=null && !contactNumber.equals("NA"))
        {
            holder.contactNumber.setText(cm.getContactNumber());            
        }
        else{
            holder.contactNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);          
        }
        if(!email.equals("null") && email!="" && email!=null && !email.equals("NA"))
        {           
            holder.email.setText(cm.getEmail());
        }
        else{           
            holder.email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }               
        holder.contactCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.contactCheckBox.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        holder.contactCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);        
        return view;
    }
    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
           boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    
   }
   private class ViewHolder{
       public TextView candidateName;      
       public TextView contactNumber;
       public TextView email;
       public CheckBox contactCheckBox;
    }
}
```

///Code in my activity. Here I am actually adding the data to the adapter.
i want the data of selected checkboxes from the list view, how would I achieve it?.

```
dataarray = datajsonobject.getJSONArray("candidateList");                   
                    CandidateAdapter ca = null;
                    final ArrayList<CandidateModel> candidateList = new ArrayList<CandidateModel>();                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dataobject = new JSONObject();
                        dataobject = dataarray.getJSONObject(i);                        
                        String candidate_name = dataobject.getString("fullName");
                        String url = dataobject.getString("url");
                        String email = dataobject.getString("email");
                        String contactNumber = dataobject.getString("contactNumber");
                        String candidateId = dataobject.getString("candidateId");
                        //CandidateModel cm = new CandidateModel(candidate_name,score);
                        CandidateModel cm = new CandidateModel();
                        cm.setJobId(job_id);
                        cm.setCandidateName(candidate_name);
                        cm.setResumeURL(url);
                        cm.setContactNumber(contactNumber);
                        cm.setEmail(email);
                        cm.setSelected(false);
                        cm.setCandidateId(candidateId);
                        candidateList.add(cm);                      
                    }                                       
                    ca = new CandidateAdapter(Candidate.this,candidateList);
                    clist.setAdapter(ca);
                    clist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {                           
                              CandidateModel selItem = candidateList.get(position);//get the selected RowItem from the list                           
                              Intent downloadResumeIntent = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        DownloadResume.class);                              
                                final String url = selItem.getResumeURL();
                                downloadResumeIntent.putExtra("url",url);
                                downloadResumeIntent.putExtra("jobId",job_id);
                                //downloadResumeIntent.putExtra("resumeUniqueID", uniqueResumeId);                              
                                startActivity(downloadResumeIntent);
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                              }
                            });
```

Comment: I see that you already have the apis written to achieve that, you have the `toggle(int position)` and boolean `isChecked(int position)` method. do you use them?

Comment: Not yet. Actually i don know how to get all the selected value to the activity, since all the code writtent to the adapter regards checkbox

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail can you tell me how to use those method to the activity to get the status as well as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add one more boolean field in adapter item modle class CandidateModel :

```
public class CandidateModel {

    private boolean isSelected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

Use isSelected field directly instead SparseBooleanArray or no need to SparseBooleanArray :

```
holder.contactCheckBox.setChecked(cm.isSelected());
holder.contactCheckBox..setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       cm.setSelected(isChecked);         
    }
});
```

Get checked all item :

```
public ArrayList<CandidateModel> getCheckAllItem(){
    ArrayList<CandidateModel> candidateModelArrayList = new ArrayList<CandidateModel>();
    for(CandidateModel model :candidateList){
        if(model.isSelected()){
           candidateModelArrayList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return candidateModelArrayList
}
```

Check item at position :

```
public boolean isItemChecked (int index){
   return candidateList.get(index).isSelected();
}
```

Comment: can you help me out for other issue, if some of list item does not have "email" and when i scroll up and then down the email and contactno set invisible from the list view.

Answer (score 0):

maintain arraylist globally in adapter maintain the check box state in the arraylist now you can get the arraylist in activity by calling the adaptet.arraylist;

Answer (score 0):

If candidateList order remains the same all the time, then it is ok to use position as Tag value.
Try putting this method in your adapter and call it from activity.

```
public ArrayList<CandidateModel> GetCheckedItems(){

    ArrayList<CandidateModel> checkedItems = new ArrayList<CandidateModel>();

    for(int position = 0; position < candidateList.size(); position++){
        if(mCheckStates.get(position))
            checkedItems.add(candidateList.get(position));
    }

    return checkedItems;
}
```

Maybe i misunderstand your question :). Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getter methods from class CandidateModel to retrieve all the data you want. eg: `selItem.getResumeURL();`

why do you need to know the checkbox's state if you know the position in the list that has been clicked? regardless of the answer you can use the already present method `adapter.isChecked(position)` to see if the checkbox is checked or not.